# Can I attach an event handler to a barchart bar in Superset?

Tags: apache-superset

Is is possible to attach event handler to a bar in a barchart?

I have a barchart that displays average income (each bar represents a province)...

What I need is: when I click a bar that represents "Illinois" for example, my dashboard will be update with data pertaining only to "Illinois".

That's something that Microsoft Power BI can do. Wondering if that's possible in Superset.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not supported for now. Unfortunately you can not customize any behaviour on bar events except checkboxes in controls area. But if you are familiar with javascript you can customize this behaviour in js scripts /superset/assets/visualizations/ after cloning repo and installation from source code.